# How to lock a resource using multithreading?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having a property sheet where I had four pages .In the second page I am having a list control and a button.And in the second page I created two threads .When I click next in the first page,I am trying enumerating the list control with some values which are being retrieved from the network .So,here the a search dialog and enumerating the list are being handled in two different threads which runs in parallel.On front of the page the search dialog got popped up and background the values from network are retrieved and list is getting enumerated with those values.During that time if I click on the client area then this search dialog is getting minimized.But this should not happen until unless the search dialog is dismissed I must not be given access to the parent window(same scenario as ModalDiaolg box,as we know until unless the child window is closed we will not be able to access the parent right,similarly scenario is required for me.)this is the code I had done for getting those threads to be run at a time.

```
    BOOL CModelSelectionView::CreateModelThread()
        {
               unsigned threadID;

          if( NULL == ( m_hModelThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(
                       NULL,
                        0,
                       &CModelSelectionView::ModelThreadProc,
                       reinterpret_cast<void*>(this),
                       0,
                       &threadID)) )
      {
               return FALSE;
      }



      return TRUE;
     }
```

//this thread is for search dialog

```
    UINT CModelSelectionView::ModelThreadProc( void* lpContext )
    {
     CModelSelectionView *pSelectModelFromList = 
      reinterpret_cast<CModelSelectionView*> (lpContext);`
      AfxSetResourceHandle(theApp.m_hDialogResource);

      CSearchingView SearchView(IDD_DIALOG_SEARCH);

     INT nRes = SearchView.DoModal();
    ::CloseHandle( pSelectModelFromList->m_hModelThread );
     pSelectModelFromList->m_hModelThread = NULL;

    _endthreadex( 0 );



 return TRUE;
}

BOOL CModelSelectionView::CreateInstallerThread()
{
    unsigned threadID;
if( NULL == ( m_hInstallerThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(
    NULL,
    0,
    &CModelSelectionView::InstallerThreadProc,
    reinterpret_cast<void*>(this),
    0,
    &threadID)) )
{
    return FALSE;
}

return TRUE;
}
```

//Second thread for Initializing the list with some values

```
UINT CModelSelectionView::InstallerThreadProc( void* lpContext )
{
    CModelSelectionView *pSelectModelFromList = 
    reinterpret_cast<CModelSelectionView*> (lpContext);
    pSelectModelFromList->m_listCtrl.DeleteAllItems();

    LVITEM lvitem;
    lvitem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvitem.iItem = 0;
    lvitem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvitem.pszText = L"";
    lvitem.cchTextMax = sizeof(lvitem.pszText);
    int nItem = pSelectModelFromList->m_listCtrl.InsertItem(&lvitem);
    ::Sleep(200);

    pSelectModelFromList->m_listCtrl.SetItemText(0,1,L"XXX");
    pSelectModelFromList->m_listCtrl.SetItemText(0,2,L"YYY");
    pSelectModelFromList->m_listCtrl.SetItemText(0,3,L"ZZZ");
    pSelectModelFromList->m_listCtrl.SetItemText(0,4,L"AAAA");


::Sleep(200);



::TerminateThread(pSelectModelFromList->m_hModelThread, 0);
    ::CloseHandle(pSelectModelFromList->m_hModelThread );
    pSelectModelFromList->m_hModelThread = NULL;

    ::CloseHandle( pSelectModelFromList->m_hInstallerThread );
    pSelectModelFromList->m_hInstallerThread = NULL;

    _endthreadex( 0 );

    return TRUE;
}
```

Until unless the search dialog is closed it should not be allowed to access the parent window.For instance when click a button and for that button handler I was calling domodal then a child dialog pop-up appears until unless we dismiss that dialog we will not be allowed to access the parent right ,similarly I have to get in this scenario.

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve that.

Can anyone please suggest me how

Answer (score 0):

Simply EnableWindow(FALSE) for the window that should not receive any input. It will still be displayed and its contents is updated, but mouse and keyboard events will not reach this window.